# Swift: Popup DatePicker on textbox with done button

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I'm creating an app that has a UITextField on it, which, when tapped / clicked, will show a Date Picker that will flyout from the bottom. Said popup panel has a Done button, which will apply whatever date is selected (default to today) to the textfield upon click / tap, of preferably YYYY-MM-DD format.

I've been digging around the net, and so far I've seen examples with an IBAction for the textfield, with various ways as to how the done button works (and most without a done button), but I was wondering if I could recycle or base it off my code for a drop down menu below:

```
let wellheadPressTest : [String] = ["PSIG", "MPAG"]
var wellboreStatusPickerView = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let wellboreStatusToolBar = UIToolbar()
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButtonWellbore = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePickerWellbore")

    wellboreStatusToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    wellboreStatusToolBar.translucent = true
    wellboreStatusToolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    wellboreStatusToolBar.sizeToFit()
    wellboreStatusToolBar.setItems([spaceButton,spaceButton,doneButtonWellbore], animated: false)
    wellboreStatusToolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    wellboreStatusPickerView.delegate = self
    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldWellbore.inputView = wellboreStatusPickerView
    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldWellbore.inputAccessoryView = wellboreStatusToolBar
}


// Various Required PickerView functions

func donePickerWellbore(){
    let row = wellboreStatusPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0);
    pickerView(wellboreStatusPickerView, didSelectRow: row, inComponent:0)
    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldWellbore.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Here's what I tried:

```
var dateSampledPickerView = UIDatePicker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let dateSampledPickerToolBar = UIToolbar()
    let doneButtonDate = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePickerDate")
    dateSampledPickerToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    dateSampledPickerToolBar.translucent = true
    dateSampledPickerToolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    dateSampledPickerToolBar.sizeToFit()
    dateSampledPickerToolBar.setItems([spaceButton,spaceButton,doneButtonDate], animated: false)
    dateSampledPickerToolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    dateSampledPickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    dateSampledPickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldDateSampled.inputView = dateSampledPickerView
    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldDateSampled.inputAccessoryView = dateSampledPickerToolBar
    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldDateSampled.delegate = self
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldDateSampled.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

func donePickerDate(){
    self.samplingWaterFormOneView.textfieldDateSampled.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

My code above does show a pop-up menu with a date picker when I top the textfield, with a done button, but the textfield doesn't get the date.

EDIT: Also tried modifying the `datePickerValueChanged` such that it doesn't have a sender, and also uses the `dateSampledPickerView` for the textfield. Didn't work.

Putting in comments in the function suggests that the `datePickerValueChanged` function isn't being called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the datePickerValueChanged function isnt being called becasue you have not set the delegate of the dateSampledPickerView.

So simply enter

```
dateSampledPickerView.delegate = self
```

*********EDIT****************

Ok so after looking closer I believe you have set the action call incorrectly. Replace this line

```
    dateSampledPickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

with

```
dateSampledPickerView.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerValueChanged", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

removing the Selector()

Comment: Hmmmm... That's what I thought too, but apparently, `Value of UIDatePicker has no member delegate`.

Comment: Thanks, that got me somewhere. Now I know via print that the function is getting called. However, it doesn't update the textfield. I tried printing out `dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateSampledPickerView.date)` but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try printing out the dateSampledPickerView.date or dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)? Also to clarify does the Done button work? As in, does the picker view disappear?

Comment: I tried printing out dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date) in my initial code, and got an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` for my troubles - it happens upon changing the DatePicker's value. I thought maybe it had to do with the sender, so I removed it per the code up there. The Done button works, it makes the pop-up disappear, but does not write anything to the textfield.

Comment: Re-added the Selector("datePickerValueChanged:") and the (sender: UIDatePicker) back fixed it (the colon is apparently important. I'm back to square one, however. It is printing an empty line.

Comment: Got it. Apparently, there was something wrong with my date formatting. Once a manual date format has been set (`dateStyle`), no other styles may be used.

Comment: Interesting. I guess that makes sense. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 5):

Here you have an example of date picker with toolbar:

```
var date: NSDate?
var timePicker: UIDatePicker?

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

func initDatePicker() {
        if self.timePicker == nil {
            self.timePicker = UIDatePicker()
            self.timePicker!.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
            self.timePicker!.addTarget(self, action: "updateDate", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            self.timePicker!.minimumDate = NSDate()
            self.timePicker!.backgroundColor = UIColor().backgroundColor()
            self.dateLabel.inputView = self.timePicker
            self.dateLabel.inputAccessoryView = self.createPickerToolBar()
        }
    }

func updateDate() {
        let picker: UIDatePicker = self.dateLabel.inputView as! UIDatePicker
        self.dateLabel.text = picker.date.stringFromDate(kDateFormatSlash)
        self.date = picker.date
        self.delegate?.didIntroduceText(self.actionTextView.text.characters.count != 0 && self.searchableTableView?.getText().characters.count != 0 && self.dateLabel.text!.characters.count != 0)
    }

    func createPickerToolBar() -> UIToolbar {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "DONE", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "doneAction")
        doneButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: kOpenSansRegular, size: kHeaderFontSize)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        doneButton.accessibilityLabel = "DoneToolbar"
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolbar.translucent = false
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolbar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        return toolbar
    }

    func doneAction() {
        self.updateDate()
        self.dateLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        self.timePicker?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: I'm missing something here. I have two text fields, each using a datepicker, and I am having to duplicate each of these functions to separate them. That seems wrong, even if it works. How can I tell the doneAction to update the right field in one function rather than repeating?

Comment: You can add tag to the datepicker and toolbar